# How to target DOM elements from new popup window, using chrome extension popup.html

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension that works fine, I reference a function and it opens a pop up.  Generally, how can I access the newly popped up html dom elements (Within the same domain) from my popup.js or popup.html document.

```
function cfs_policy() { 
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, 
function(tabs) {
        // query the active tab, which will be only one tab
        //and inject the script in it
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {file: 
"links/cfs_policy.js"});
    });
}
function d_cfs_policy() {   
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, 
function(tabs) {
        // query the active tab, which will be only one tab
        //and inject the script in it
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {file: 
"links/d_cfs_policy.js"});
    });
}
document.getElementById('cfs').addEventListener('click', cfs);
document.getElementById('d_cfs').addEventListener('click', d_cfs);
document.getElementById('cfs_policy').addEventListener('click', 
cfs_policy);
document.getElementById('d_cfs_policy').addEventListener('click', 
d_cfs_policy);
```

[snippet] cfs_policy.js

```
function cfs_policy(){
var x = document.getElementById('tabFrame');
var y = x.contentDocument ;
var els = y.getElementsByTagName('table')[8]
els.getElementsByClassName('actionIcon editIconBtn')[0].click()
els.focus();
}
cfs_policy()
```

[snippet] d_csf_policy.js

```
function d_cfs_policy(){
console.log('test')
}
d_cfs_policy()
```

[snippet] popup.html

```
<button class="collapsible" id="cfs">CFS Objects</button> 
<div class="content">
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<button id="d_cfs">Download</button>
<button class="collapsible" id="cfs_policy">Policies</button> 
<div class="content"><button id="d_cfs_policy">Download</button></div>
</td>   
</tr>
</table>
</div>  
</div>
```

Comment: If you want to access the web page you can do it only inside the content script (the code you run with executeScript). Otherwise it's unclear what those "newly popped up html dom elements" are, why "same domain" is mentioned (extensions run in their own separate URL which doesn't have domains) and what kind of access is envisioned.

Comment: Just want to make sure I'm not providing the wrong info, but I was under the impressions that there is a security feature SOP, same origin policy that restricts interaction between documents (or scripts) that have different origins.  That's why I mentioned it's in the same domain.  

So what I need is the html code to reference the id, that's listening on cfs_policy.js, when this is called, it opens a popup window, and any further code gets executed on the original page, not the new popup.  

When I added console.log('test') to the content script, it executes under the popup.html page...

Comment: I need it to execute under the new window.  Another fix would be to access it by targeting the window.name.

Comment: I still don't understand the question. The content script (the thing you inject with executeScript or declare in manifest.json under content_scripts) runs in the web page, not in the browser_action (or page_action) popup so the only explanation for seeing console.log from a content script in your popup page is that you explicitly load the content script in your popup.html, which doesn't usually make any sense since the popup page is totally different from a web page. Anyway, I don't see the full picture here.

Comment: I was just using the wrong verbiage.  I'm not referring to the Popup.html.  I'm referring to another window that opens from the main page.  How to access that.  I'm doing my research on chrome tabs and indexes so I think I got it figured out.  But the point is, when I click on a link from my popup.html, it runs a function from my main page that opens a window (another popup), and I want the DOM from that popup.  
I got it to work with window.open(url), but I need the actual function to run, and gather those elements when it opens.

Comment: If that other popup is also your extension's page, see [this answer](/a/54715122/).

Comment: It's not, I'm working from a commercial page and using their elements/functions.  I think I have it almost figured out.  The open.window() showed me alot, and I understand that chrome tabs will always refer to the open page, including recent popups. So I just gotta think it through.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: If that's a web page popup then it runs in a different process meaning your extension script cannot access its content directly. Only a content script can do it, and then communicate with your extension script via [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) (note, only simple JSON types are transferable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually did what I was trying to do all along.  Target the window by name.  You can see on line 8, when the button is clicked, it opens a window.  Then on line 14, I referenced the same window and I'm free to get the objs from line 15 down.  Thanks for the help.   I hope someone reading this could understand and find it useful.

```
function cfs_policy(){
var test;
var x = document.getElementById('tabFrame');
var y = x.contentDocument ;
var els = y.getElementById('profileTable')
els = els.getElementsByClassName('listItem')
for(i=0;i<els.length;i++){
    els[i].getElementsByClassName('actionIcon editIconBtn')[0].click()
    setTimeout(function(){
        test = String(window.origin)
        test = test.substring(8,)
        test = test.replace(/\:.*/,'');
        test = test.split('.')
        var existingWin = window.open('', test[0]+ "_" + test[1] + "_" + test[2] + "_" + test[3] + "_profileObjDlg");
        var lab = existingWin.document.getElementsByClassName('label')
        var val = existingWin.document.getElementsByName('objName')
        var sel = existingWin.document.getElementsByTagName('select')
        test = lab[0].innerText + val[0].value + "\n"
        var p;
        var cat;
        for (let p = 5; p < 62; p++) {
            try {
                if (sel[p-1].value == 0) {cat = "Allow"}
                else if (sel[p-1].value == 1) {cat = "Block"}
                else if (sel[p-1].value == 2) {cat = "BWM"}
                else if (sel[p-1].value == 3) {cat = "Confirm"}
                else if (sel[p-1].value == 4) {cat = "Passphrase"}
                test += lab[p].innerText + " : " + cat + "\n"           
                console.log(test)
            }
            catch(error) {
            }

        }
        }, 3000);
    }
}
cfs_policy()
```